# How to store Memory Stream In DataTemp in.net core 3 In Controller's Action

Tags: c#, .net-core, controller

I want to hold data in TempData fileGuid is key while a method called by ajax action. 
below method called by ajax and in ajax response I call again Ajax GET DownloadExcel() method.

```
public IActionResult ExportExcel(List<string> wfsId, List<string> centerId, List<string> poolId,
   List<string> payer, List<string> csId, List<string> agingBucket, int timezoneOffset) {

   try {
      var memoryStream = ExcelHelper.ExportDataSet(dataTable);
      memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

      TempData[fileGuid] = memoryStream.ToArray();    
      var retvalue = new { FileGuid = fileGuid, FileName = fileName };

      return Ok(retvalue);
   }

   public ActionResult DownloadExcel(string fileGuid, string fileName) {
      if (TempData[fileGuid] != null) {

         // var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(TempData[fileGuid].ToString());
         // byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(deserializeObject.ToString());

         byte[] data = TempData[fileGuid] as byte[];

         return File(data, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing with TempData is it null?

Comment: Make sure you have enabled this in startup services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>();
    services.AddSession();

Comment: @Abdul jabbar  
I have added  service.AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
Is it work?

Comment: While I'm using TempData 500 Error as a response in ajax

Comment: TempData is not active by default in .Net Core. You need to do some changes in ConfigureServices and Configure. Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1.

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old, but once you retrieve something from `TempData` it is marked for deletion. You retrieve twice; once in the conditional, and once again when populating the result. Use `Peek()` to get at the object without deleting it.